# Do two faces of any 3-connected planar graph have at most one edge in common?

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

In graph theory, a connected graph $G$ is said to be $3$-vertex-connected (or $3$-connected) if it has more than $3$ vertices and remains connected whenever fewer than $3$ vertices are removed. I was thinking about what the title said above.

**problem:**  Do any two faces of any 3-connected planar graph  have at most one edge in common?

**My intuitive analysis:** Suppose that two faces are associated with at least two edges. If the two edges are adjacent, there exists clearly a 2-cut set.
[image: ![{u,v} is 2-cut set]

If not, I think one of the cases is the following:
[image]
We still seem to be able to find a 2-cut.

It seems to me that the question I am considering is correct. But my analysis is actually not too strict. I'd like to  prove it strictly. Of course it would be nice to find a counterexample.

Comment: I think one reformulation of your question would be: "Is the dual graph of a polyhedral graph always simple?", which [seems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_graph) to be true because 3-vertex connectivity implies 3-edge connectivity which implies the dual graph is simple. I don't know the proof for these claims so I'll just leave it here as a comment.

Comment: @AnilCh I think you're right if the fact that the dual graph of a 3-edge connected planar graph is simple is true.