# How high the connectivity of a planar graph can ensure that any two faces share at most two vertices?

Tags: graph-theory, polyhedra, planar-graphs

Once I asked the following question.

**Question 1 (solved):**  Do any two faces share with at most one edge in a 3-connected plane graph?

- [Do two faces of any 3-connected planar graph have at most one edge in common?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4209033/do-two-faces-of-any-3-connected-planar-graph-have-at-most-one-edge-in-common)

As *anilch* reminded, the dual graph of a 3-vertex-connected (or,3-edge -connected) planar graph is simple.  So the question is solved.

The following broader question might be interesting.

**Question 2:**  Do any two faces share with at most two vertices in a 3-vertex-connected plane graph?

If ''3" is not guaranteed, what if we choose  "4" or "5"? Disprove it or prove it.

I'm looking for some counterexamples, but so far I haven't found any.

---

Without finding a counterexample, I thought the following claim would be true:

**Claim:** Let $G$ be a $3$-vertex-connected graph. Then any two faces $f_1$ and $f_2$ have at most two vertices in common.  Further  if $f_1$ and $f_2$ share two vertices $v_1,v_2$, then the edge $v_1v_2$ is the unique edge shared by $f_1$ and $f_2$.

**A Outline of proof:** If there are two faces $f_1$ and $f_2$ such that they have three or more vertices in common. By properly choosing two shared vertices $x,y$, we can construct a  closed curve that is crosses through these two vertices and falls in $f_1$ and $f_2$. By the closed curve, we can see clearly that $x, y$ is a 2-cut set, a contradiction.

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: It's a bit of overkill, but one can show that the $3$-connected planar graphs are exactly the ["polyhedral graphs"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyhedral_graph) (representing the vertex-and-edge skeleton of a convex polyhedron). Since a polyhedron has the property you describe, the result follows.

Comment: Thanks! I am not yet familiar with polyhedra.  You say "Since a polyhedron has the property you describe, the result follows."  Is it obvious from the definition that a polyhedron has this property?

Comment: The obviousness would seem to depend upon which fundamental definition of polyhedron you assume, so I suppose I'm *really* suggesting that you should attempt to prove the property for convex polyhedra. An advantage of that approach is that you get a geometric assist from the fact that each face lies in a plane, each edge lies in a line, and each vertex corresponds to a point where three-or-more planes meet.

Comment: It's wonderful and intuitive.  Thanks!